# CRMAP7007: Error reading local file area registry

Tags: clearcase-remote-client

When getting list of views in IBM Rational ClearTeam Explorer, it reports the error message"CRMAP7007: Error reading local file area registry." So I cannot retrieve my views list after that message shows. Does any one have idea about how to resolve this problem?

Many Thanks for your kind help!

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved. Delete the ***.ccase_wvreg_lockfile*** from C:\Users\*username*\

Answer (score 0):

Note: the thread "[CRMAP7007 Error reading local file area registry](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=c806db64-f48c-4b87-bca5-b872e4648dbb)" gives a bit more details:

[image: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/ajax/download?nodeId=d439127a-629d-49e1-993c-f5b3a28fc754]

It is interesting because it reminds you of the debug options that exist with CTE:

> To get a better idea of why the error is thrown you can look in the workspace log file.
>   This file is by default `<user home>\.Rational\workspace\.metadata\.log`
>
> You can also launch CTE in debug mode by creating a `.options` file in the directory that he executable is in.  The content of that file should be as below:

```
# -------------- CCRC Tracing Options File -----------------
# All line preceeded with a # sign are not evaluated.

# ------Server Tracing-------
# subsystems available:
# CCRC - Core general tracing related to CCRC server operations
# CCWEB- CCWeb(CGI operations)
# SUM -  UCM specific

com.ibm.rational.clearcase/server_trace=true
com.ibm.rational.clearcase/server_trace/subsys=CCRC:CCWEB:SUM
com.ibm.rational.clearcase/server_trace/level=4

# ------Client Only Tracing-------
# Parameters available:
# HTTP_CLIENT - Tracing specific to HTTP communications
# CTRC_UI -     Tracing specific to the user interface
# CTRC_CORE -   For client core tracing

com.ibm.rational.clearcase/client_trace=true
com.ibm.rational.clearcase/client_trace/params=HTTP_CLIENT:4 CTRC_UI:3 CTRC_CORE:3

com.ibm.rational.clearcase/client_trace/output=file
com.ibm.rational.clearcase/client_trace/file_name=C:/temp/cte_debug.out
# -------------- END CCRC Tracing Options File -----------------
```

> With that file created, launch CTE from the command line using the `-debug` option:
>
> C:\Program Files\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\RemoteClient>ctexplorer.exe -debug